# From XmlDocument To XmlReader .Net

Tags: .net, xmldocument, xmlreader

After an advice from a user that answered to my question I'm tring to convert my XmlDocument code to XmlReader code but I'm having some troubles.

This is XML (generated from php-mysql Page)

```
<row>
<idLink>64</idLink>
<idHost>3</idHost>
<url>http://www.google.com</url>
</row>
<row>
<idLink>68</idLink>
<idHost>4</idHost>
<url>http://www.bing.com</url>
</row>
..... until about 10000 rows
```

This is my XmlDocument code:

```
   xmlDoc.Load("http://www.myUrl.com/list.php");
      if (xmlDoc.DocumentElement != null){
          foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.DocumentElement)
             {
              if (node.Name == "row")
                {
                  list.Add(new Links { 
                       idLink = Convert.ToInt32(node.ChildNodes[0].InnerText),
                       idHost = Convert.ToInt32(node.ChildNodes[1].InnerText),
                       url = node.ChildNodes[2].InnerText }); 
                  }
             }  
             return list;
```

Now I have some trouble to Convert in XmlReader, I tried many code but I can't handle it.

```
using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader("http://myUrl.com/list.php"))
         { 
          if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) 
           ?????
```

Comment: Trying to (robustly) read xml with XmlReader is, frankly, hard. What is it that you are trying to do here? what is your objective? and what is the size of the xml?

Comment: @MarcGravell The size of xml is , as i wrote in the xml code , about 10000 rows. I'm reading a xml e put in a List<Link>.

Comment: What fails with XmlDocument? Have you tried XmlSerializer? XElement?

Comment: @MarcGravell the problem is i need to keep in memory this Object List<Link> and they are about 10000. As i read in this article http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/joe_ferner/performance_linq_to_sql_vs.html the performance are better with XmlReader

Comment: @MarcGravell The problem is the Ram and Pc's. They are (most of them) Virtual Machine with 512 Mb Ram dedicated and i would increase performance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are doing read only operations on an xml file then you can you use `XmlReader` but as @Marc Gravell points out it is difficult.

In this situation I will create a class that wraps an `XPathDocument` using an `XmlReader`. I then create an `XPathNavigator` to read the data. Here's an example:

```
public class MyXmlReader
{
    public MyXmlReader(string xml)
    {
        StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xml);

        XPathDocument xml = new XPathDocument(XmlReader.Create(sReader));

        xmlNav = xml.CreateNavigator();
    }

    private XPathNavigator xmlNav = null;


    public MyDataModel ReadMyDataModel()
    {
        MyDataModel model = new MyDataModel();

        model.Read(xmlNav);

        return model;
    }
}
```

As shown above, the reading of the data can then be encapsulated into an associated object model. You can see some details in my answer on this question:

[How do I manipulate an XML document one parent element at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839994/how-do-i-manipulate-an-xml-document-one-parent-element-at-a-time/8841036#8841036)

Comment: ok, let me know if you have any more questions. I use this method frequently for read only access to xml files.

Answer (score 84):

You can use

```
XmlReader xmlReader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDoc);
```

See: http://blog.jongallant.com/2007/01/convert-xmldocument-to-xmlreader.html

Comment: Unfortunately the link is broken